# UILabel always animates to same spot

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel called "nameLabel" and I have it inside an animation block so that this happens:

```
_nameLabel.alpha = 1;
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50, 50);
_nameLabel.transform = translate;
```

I thought that animates the UILabel to the spot I specify but it just animates from the above spot to the place where I have it in the Interface Builder. Any help here?

Comment: The above code will move your label 50 points down and to the right. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the animation block and other associated code? I am not sure what `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` does with the label, but if you want to animate the frame location, you can use this:

```
CGRect frame = _nameLabel.frame;
frame.origin.y = 100; //Desired height, origin.x can be modified as well. 
//You can also change the frame size here but it wont work on UILabels, you will need `CGAffineTransformScale` for that.

[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^ {

                     [_nameLabel setFrame:frame];

                 }
                 completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

Edit: The other way:

```
CGRect frame = _nameLabel.frame;
frame.origin.y = 100;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[_nameLabel setFrame: newFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Current state is probably the current location of the label, try that first but if nothing happens, remove `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` or set the frame of the label to another location before the animation, and move it to its initial (the one in the xib file) position in the animation block, its your call.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using animation blocks with [UIView beginAnimates:@"animation" context:NULL]; But your solution is what I was using before that. I just can't get it to work with my way. Thanks for the help though man.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out because Autolayout cause a lot of problems.

Try to deselect 'Use Autolayout'

It solves to me all the problems trying to translate objects.